# Fade-In Fade-Out Animation for UIImageViews?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, fade

I have two UIImageView - `leftSide` and `rightSide`, which I would like to fade in and then fade out, one after the other, in a loop.

How do I do this in Xcode?  I tried `CABasicAnimation` but this did not work (I'm not sure why, no errors at all, the images do not fade).

Thanks!

EDIT: This is the code I was using:

```
-(void)leftSideFade{
    CABasicAnimation *blink;
    blink = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    blink.duration = 1.0;
    blink.repeatCount = 5;
    blink.autoreverses = YES;
    blink.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    blink.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    [leftSideStart.layer addAnimation:blink forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
    [self rightSideFade];
}

-(void)rightSideFade{
    CABasicAnimation *blink;
    blink = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    blink.duration = 1.0;
    blink.repeatCount = 5;
    blink.autoreverses = YES;
    blink.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    blink.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    [rightSideStart.layer addAnimation:blink forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
    [self leftSideFade];
}
```

Comment: Show they code you were using

Comment: Dont set repeat count here to 5..set it to 1

Comment: I tried that before but it returned an error - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address 0x7fff53ffff8)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)fadeIn 
{
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeIn Animation" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
  imageView.alpha = 1.0;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Try this to.

Comment: I tried this but my UIImageView just shows up, it does not fade.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about a simpler way with UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion: ?
There you just change alpha of your views and they will fade in/out
Here is a sample code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                 animations:^
{
    //Here you set values you want to see in the end of animation
    leftView.alpha = 0.0f;
    rightView.alpha = 1.0f;
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    //something to do after animation finished
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  Could you explain a little more what I would have to write?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following :

```
- (void) fadeinRightFadwOutLeft {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"start" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    rightSide.alpha = 0.0;
    leftSide.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void) fadeinLeftFadwOutRight {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"start" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    leftSide.alpha = 0.0;
    rightSide.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Samkit, I tried this but I get the error - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address 0x7fff53ffff8) - any ideas?

Comment: Which one you tried..mine one or yours with count = 1;

Comment: I copied and pasted it exactly how you wrote it in the answer (changing leftSide and rightSide to the correct names) but it still returned this error.  What do you mean by count?  Sorry if I sound silly, I am new to iOS development :)

Comment: What is your requirement ?

Comment: I have GameViewController, when it is called, I would like two imageviews to fade in and fade out one after the other until the user presses a button, which I can code as imageview.hidden = YES.  It is just this animationg that won't show up

Comment: you need to do..one after another ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html